# While loop function explanation and general input explanation

Tags: python

I have a function which goes as follows

```
def f(xs):
    i = 0
    r=[]
    while -len(xs) < i< len(xs):
        i,v = xs[i]
        r.append(v)
    return r
```

I was wondering if I could get a run down on how the function is working entirely as I have been trying to get my head around the while loop and append function but I'm having a complete brain fart.

Also could I please get an explanation as to why the input below returns a non-terminating execution

```
 zs = f([(1, 'a'), (-2, 'b'), (4,'c'), (-2, 'd')])
```

Comment: Please fix the code's indentation.

Comment: Which version of python are you using? In the link I included below, the example does terminate properly.

Comment: With that input, your function ends as soon as it gets to the tuple with a `4`, because `-4 < 4 < 4` is `False` and the loop ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Function does:

1. Reads a parameter `xs`
2. Keep looping as long as the condition `-len(xs) < i< len(xs)` is `True`,
   meaning, as long as `i` is more than `-len(xs)` (negative of length of the `xs` list you pass to `f`) **AND** less than `len(xs)` as well.
3. Inside this `while` loop:

   a - reads two values from each element of list `xs` (presuming to be a
   tuple as you give us an example of it's use) and assign it to `i` and `v`

   b - add each `v` to the list `r` (`r.append(v)`)
4. Return the list `r`

Now, concerning your example and based on the above explanation, I don't see how it's a non-terminating execution as the the condition of the while loop will be `False` after it reaches tuple(4,'c') when -4 < 4 < 4 is `False` condition.

So, at the end, `f` function will return to you a list: ['a','b','c'].

Comment: ```i``` is not being incremented within the loop suite.

Comment: @wwii, `i` is getting it's value from each tuple

Comment: Grrrr,  I hate it when I do that.

Answer (score -1):

Use [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/) - It's a tool that will step through your code line by line, and you'll see what's happening.

[link to your code](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+f%28xs%29%3A%0A++++i+%3D+0%0A++++r%3D%5B%5D%0A++++while+-len%28xs%29+%3C+i+%3C+len%28xs%29%3A%0A++++++++i,v+%3D+xs%5Bi%5D%0A++++++++r.append%28v%29%0A++++return+r%0A%0Azs+%3D+f%28%5B%281,+'a'%29,+%28-2,+'b'%29,+%284,'c'%29,+%28-2,+'d'%29%5D%29&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D)

Comment: It wasn't working when I put in the input but your link worked and it was a great visualization to see what was going on. I'd upvote you if i could haha

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I appreciate the sentiment, and don't appreciate the downvotes I got :( (edit: someone did upvote me. Thanks!). It's a great tool, I just wish more beginners knew about it, and it was 100% relevant to your problem.